# Channel permission update for members?

Tags: python, api, discord.py

When I change the permission of a role in a voice channel, the members that are inside of it don't get muted. They need to leave and then re-enter to get muted.
Here is a piece of my code:

```
cat = ctx.guild.get_channel(categorychannel)
everyone = ctx.guild.default_role
perm = cat.overwrites_for(everyone)
perm.speak = False
channel = await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel("test", category=cat)
await channel.set_permissions(everyone, overwrite=perm)
```

Would it be possible to have something similar to an update function?

Comment: I don't think anything can be done about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I found that we can move the member to the same channel that it update the permissions.
So... you can use these functions:

```
member.move_to(channel)
```

Or

```
member.edit(voice_channel=channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only real way I can see this being achieved through a bot is by moving the member to another VC and then back again. **The bot will need the `move_members` permission.**

If you already have a temporary voice channel set up to move them to, then you can do something like so:

```
# Bear in mind that the user needs to be in a voice channel for this to work
@bot.command()
async def update(ctx, target: discord.Member):
    temp_vc = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, id=112233445566778899)
    prev_vc = target.voice.channel
    await target.move_to(temp_vc)  # is a coro, therefore needs to be awaited
    await target.move_to(prev_vc)
```

Feel free to also add whatever exception handling you'd like.

---

### References:

- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)
- [`Member.move_to()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to)